# How often does Ginter restock?

Tags: pokemon-legends-arceus

Near Galaxy Hall, the merchant Ginter occasionally sells a random item at a fixed price. After buying an item, I can't buy from him again until he restocks with a different item.

How often does Ginter restock his items? Will he restock with a different item if I don't buy his current item?

Comment: [As of v1.1.0](https://nintendoeverything.com/pokemon-legends-arceus-version-1-1-0-update-patch-notes/), Ginter now offers multiple options when buying items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Serebii](https://www.serebii.net/legendsarceus/ginkgoguild.shtml):

> He will offer you an item for a short time, with it changing after you have captured 20 Pokémon.

Comment: I've confirmed myself that Ginter will restock even if you haven't bought his previous item.